# SVG File not working in Browser and ignoring rect values

Tags: html, svg, inkscape

Hello I have made an SVG File in Inkscape but it does not render correctly in other browsers.
The problem is with parts like

```
    <rect
       style="opacity:1;fill:#5d536c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:15.1928;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="rect68790"
       width="58.56908"
       height="24.113741"
       x="297.3429"
       y="131.90263"
       ry="12.05687"
       rx="0" />
The browser completely ignores the ry value while inkscape doesn't.
```

The problem is for example where the purple smoke comes out the gray box should be round and not sharp corners.

The full file is this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   width="1920"
   height="1080"
   viewBox="0 0 508 285.75001"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg5"
   sodipodi:docname="test123.svg"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (c68e22c387, 2021-05-23)"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
 id="namedview99"
 pagecolor="#ffffff"
 bordercolor="#666666"
 borderopacity="1.0"
 inkscape:pageshadow="2"
 inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
 inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
 showgrid="false"
 inkscape:zoom="0.31692708"
 inkscape:cx="850.35333"
 inkscape:cy="918.19228"
 inkscape:window-width="1342"
 inkscape:window-height="1040"
 inkscape:window-x="291"
 inkscape:window-y="202"
 inkscape:window-maximized="0"
 inkscape:current-layer="layer1" />
  <defs
 id="defs2">
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient32076">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop32072" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop32074" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient32070">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop32066" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop32068" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient32064">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop32060" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop32062" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient32058">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop32054" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop32056" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient32052">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop32048" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop32050" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   id="linearGradient7739">
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#2b4cc0;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="0"
     id="stop7735" />
  <stop
     style="stop-color:#020051;stop-opacity:1"
     offset="1"
     id="stop7737" />
</linearGradient>
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient7739"
   id="linearGradient7741"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32070"
   id="linearGradient7743"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32058"
   id="linearGradient7745"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32076"
   id="linearGradient7747"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32064"
   id="linearGradient7749"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32052"
   id="linearGradient7751"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1150.9026)" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32052"
   id="linearGradient163134"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32058"
   id="linearGradient163136"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32064"
   id="linearGradient163138"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32070"
   id="linearGradient163140"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient32076"
   id="linearGradient163142"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
<linearGradient
   xlink:href="#linearGradient7739"
   id="linearGradient163144"
   gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
   gradientTransform="matrix(4.3284139,0,0,4.3284463,-170.16912,-1172.3799)"
   x1="42.761623"
   y1="289.71027"
   x2="92.342239"
   y2="312.96735" />
  </defs>
  <g
 id="layer1">
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#373748;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:3.2279;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect157863"
   width="508"
   height="285.75"
   x="-3.5527137e-15"
   y="0" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#901fdf;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:54.6378;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect66781"
   width="254"
   height="285.75"
   x="253.99998"
   y="0"
   ry="0" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#81e419;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:70.423;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect66037"
   width="254"
   height="285.75"
   x="-3.5527137e-15"
   y="0" />
<rect
   style="fill:#282828;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:9.09124"
   id="rect3838"
   width="6.2210879"
   height="88.961555"
   x="49.066944"
   y="113.72136"
   ry="3.110544" />
<rect
   style="fill:#282828;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:9.09124"
   id="rect2524"
   width="6.2210879"
   height="88.961555"
   x="27.77853"
   y="113.72136"
   ry="3.110544" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#7c6f91;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:44.3474;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect68265"
   width="186.23875"
   height="59.90926"
   x="288.99066"
   y="177.24342"
   ry="11.595347" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#5d536c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:56.59;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect68161"
   width="203.74776"
   height="34.517525"
   x="280.23624"
   y="221.74367"
   ry="17.258762" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#9d93ac;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:29.5361;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect68423"
   width="58.56908"
   height="91.136635"
   x="297.3429"
   y="131.90263"
   ry="45.568317"
   rx="29.284542" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse70498"
   cx="334.504"
   cy="128.34595"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139246"
   cx="330.28552"
   cy="111.89342"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="path69822"
   cx="318.47369"
   cy="124.97108"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#5d536c;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:15.1928;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect68790"
   width="58.56908"
   height="24.113741"
   x="297.3429"
   y="131.90263"
   ry="12.05687"
   rx="0" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#9d93ac;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:20.1992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect69044"
   width="58.56908"
   height="42.623417"
   x="297.3429"
   y="180.41589"
   ry="21.311708"
   rx="0" />
<rect
   style="opacity:1;fill:#9d93ac;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:20.1992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rect69666"
   width="58.56908"
   height="42.623417"
   x="297.3429"
   y="166.91646"
   ry="14.764894"
   rx="0" />
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:56.7925px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Heavy';-inkscape-font-specification:'Franklin Gothic Heavy, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.41981"
   x="362.17511"
   y="218.17735"
   id="text75613"><tspan
     id="tspan75611"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:56.7925px;font-family:'Franklin Gothic Heavy';-inkscape-font-specification:'Franklin Gothic Heavy, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#f8f8f8;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1.41981"
     x="362.17511"
     y="218.17735">CO²</tspan></text>
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139244"
   cx="328.59811"
   cy="92.488113"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139248"
   cx="303.70895"
   cy="110.62791"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139250"
   cx="305.81812"
   cy="80.676338"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139242"
   cx="307.08368"
   cy="99.659752"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139252"
   cx="346.3158"
   cy="77.723343"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139254"
   cx="295.27182"
   cy="61.270943"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#38027e;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139256"
   cx="295.27182"
   cy="61.270943"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139258"
   cx="334.08215"
   cy="69.707916"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139260"
   cx="307.9274"
   cy="67.628548"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139262"
   cx="322.27032"
   cy="42.287319"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139264"
   cx="357.70581"
   cy="39.756283"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139266"
   cx="331.55115"
   cy="43.553043"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#410099;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:52.165;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139268"
   cx="341.67548"
   cy="41.865604"
   rx="16.874037"
   ry="17.186647" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#5e29da;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:16.9651;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse139270"
   cx="334.43976"
   cy="75.438927"
   rx="5.4877548"
   ry="5.5894217" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#5e29da;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse149965"
   cx="341.71078"
   cy="45.050442"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<ellipse
   style="opacity:1;fill:#5e29da;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:31.2992;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="ellipse149967"
   cx="314.78659"
   cy="98.561607"
   rx="10.124422"
   ry="10.311989" />
<path
   id="rect2963"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 14.920909,103.09258 h 52.533823 l 26.166732,49.62563 H 41.087621 Z" />
<path
   id="path6742"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7741);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 17.825571,104.35176 h 48.394764 l 24.496467,47.10726 H 42.322029 Z" />
<path
   id="path7427"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 41.656579,154.13374 h 52.53384 l 26.166731,49.62572 H 67.823314 Z" />
<path
   id="path7429"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7747);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 44.56126,155.39294 h 48.394768 l 24.496452,47.10734 H 69.057716 Z" />
<path
   id="path7435"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 69.505481,103.09258 h 52.533839 l 26.16673,49.62563 H 95.67221 Z" />
<path
   id="path7437"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#0055d4;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 72.410154,104.35176 h 48.394766 l 24.49646,47.10726 H 96.906613 Z" />
<path
   id="path7439"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 96.241166,154.13374 h 52.533844 l 26.16672,49.62572 H 122.4079 Z" />
<path
   id="path7441"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#0055d4;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 99.145842,155.39294 h 48.394768 l 24.49646,47.10734 h -48.39478 z" />
<path
   id="path7443"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 69.505481,103.09258 h 52.533839 l 26.16673,49.62563 H 95.67221 Z" />
<path
   id="path7445"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7743);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 72.410154,104.35176 h 48.394766 l 24.49646,47.10726 H 96.906613 Z" />
<path
   id="path7447"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 96.241166,154.13374 h 52.533844 l 26.16672,49.62572 H 122.4079 Z" />
<path
   id="path7449"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7749);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 99.145842,155.39294 h 48.394768 l 24.49646,47.10734 h -48.39478 z" />
<path
   id="path7451"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 124.09007,103.09258 h 52.53383 l 26.16672,49.62563 H 150.2568 Z" />
<path
   id="path7453"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7745);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 126.99474,104.35176 h 48.39476 l 24.49646,47.10726 h -48.39477 z" />
<path
   id="path7455"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 150.82575,154.13374 h 52.53383 l 26.16673,49.62572 h -52.53383 z" />
<path
   id="path7457"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient7751);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 153.73043,155.39294 h 48.39476 l 24.49646,47.10734 h -48.39477 z" />
<text
   xml:space="preserve"
   style="font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;font-size:61.0903px;line-height:1.25;font-family:sans-serif;fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none;stroke-width:1.52727"
   x="44.74015"
   y="256.24258"
   id="text159126"><tspan
     id="tspan159124"
     style="font-style:normal;font-variant:normal;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-size:61.0903px;font-family:'Bauhaus 93';-inkscape-font-specification:'Bauhaus 93, Normal';font-variant-ligatures:normal;font-variant-caps:normal;font-variant-numeric:normal;font-variant-east-asian:normal;fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:1.52727"
     x="44.74015"
     y="256.24258">SOLAR</tspan></text>
<path
   id="path163090"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="M 14.920909,81.615249 H 67.454732 L 93.621464,131.24093 H 41.087621 Z" />
<path
   id="path163092"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163144);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="M 17.825571,82.87444 H 66.220335 L 90.716802,129.9817 H 42.322029 Z" />
<path
   id="path163094"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 41.656579,132.65646 h 52.53384 l 26.166731,49.62572 H 67.823314 Z" />
<path
   id="path163096"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163142);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 44.56126,133.91566 h 48.394768 l 24.496452,47.10733 H 69.057716 Z" />
<path
   id="path163098"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 69.505481,81.615249 h 52.533839 l 26.16673,49.625691 H 95.67221 Z" />
<path
   id="path163100"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#0055d4;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 72.410154,82.87444 h 48.394766 l 24.49646,47.10727 H 96.906613 Z" />
<path
   id="path163102"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 96.241166,132.65646 h 52.533844 l 26.16672,49.62572 H 122.4079 Z" />
<path
   id="path163104"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#0055d4;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 99.145842,133.91566 h 48.394768 l 24.49646,47.10733 h -48.39478 z" />
<path
   id="path163106"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 69.505481,81.615249 h 52.533839 l 26.16673,49.625691 H 95.67221 Z" />
<path
   id="path163108"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163140);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 72.410154,82.87444 h 48.394766 l 24.49646,47.10727 H 96.906613 Z" />
<path
   id="path163110"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 96.241166,132.65646 h 52.533844 l 26.16672,49.62572 H 122.4079 Z" />
<path
   id="path163112"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163138);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 99.145842,133.91566 h 48.394768 l 24.49646,47.10733 h -48.39478 z" />
<path
   id="path163114"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 124.09007,81.615249 h 52.53383 l 26.16672,49.625691 H 150.2568 Z" />
<path
   id="path163116"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163136);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 126.99474,82.87444 h 48.39476 l 24.49646,47.10727 h -48.39477 z" />
<path
   id="path163118"
   style="opacity:1;fill:#dbe3e2;stroke-width:3.97449"
   d="m 150.82575,132.65646 h 52.53383 l 26.16673,49.62572 h -52.53383 z" />
<path
   id="path163120"
   style="opacity:1;fill:url(#linearGradient163134);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.66134"
   d="m 153.73043,133.91566 h 48.39476 l 24.49646,47.10733 h -48.39477 z" />
<rect
   style="fill:#dedbe3;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:3.52043"
   id="rect2096"
   width="16.14843"
   height="44.569672"
   x="299.70419"
   y="162.53352"
   ry="8.0742149" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please don't paste dummy text into questions to circumvent SO's quality controls.

Comment: The browsers seem to be following https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/shapes.html whereas inkscape isn't. What roundness are you really expecting if rx="0"

Comment: In svg the rounded corner is an elliptic arc where rx and ry are the ones specified for the rectangle. If you try to draw an ellipse with rx="0" you will get a straight line

Comment: I guess you need to go here: https://inkscape.org/contribute/report-bugs/